# Running livestreamer from java

Tags: java, cmd, twitch

I try to make a little java program that allows me to search for twitch streams and open one in livestreamer and vlc.

So i have this method which should run livestreamer.

```
public static void runLiveStreamer(String channel, String quality) throws IOException{

      String cmd = new String("livestreamer.exe twitch.tv/" + channel + " " + quality);

      System.out.println(cmd);

      Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd); 

      return;
}
```

I run my code and nothing happens, it doesn't throw an exception or stops working.
As you can see i have additional line of code that prints out the command i execute. When i run it through cmd it works fine. How can i make it work ?

Thanks for help in advance and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

When you run some application through Runtime.getRuntime().exec() you need to wait till application terminates. I was terminating livestreamer when runLiveStreamer() method ended.

Updated code (this while loop is working untill livestreamer terminates, you can also use proc.wait() if you dont need output)

```
public static void runLiveStreamer(String channel, String quality) throws IOException{

      String[] cmd  = new String[]{"livestreamer.exe", "twitch.tv/"+channel, quality};

      Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

      InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream());
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
      String line=null;
      while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
          System.out.println(line);    
      }
```